# Use the remainder theorem to find $P(2)$ where $P(x)=-x^4+3x^3-4x+7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Use the remainder theorem to find $P(2)$ where $P(x)=-x^4+3x^3-4x+7$

Quotient = ?

Remainder = $P(2)$ = ?

Comment: you know how to do synthetic division?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the scheme: pull down the first coefficient; then multiply it by $2$, writing the result in the free space under $3$; do the sum, repeat.

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc|c}
& -1 & 3 & 0 & -4 & 7 \\
2& \downarrow & -2  & 2  &  4  & 0 \\
\hline
 &-1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 7
\end{array}
$$

Quotient of the division by $x-2$: $-x^3+x^2+2x$, remainder $7$.